# How to make Arrays reactive in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to add a simple hover effect on images with Vue, so that on hover the second item in the array of images in shown. I cannot work out the best way to constantly update the templates data if the data has changed. I tried Computed, didn't work either for me.

Everything updates fine in console.log() for the methods. But not for watchers or computed.

I see that watch works only on Mount, but not on mouseenter.

```
         <div class="cursor-pointer" v-for="(image, index) in images" :key="index"
                  @mouseenter="hoverEnter(index)"
                  @mouseleave="hoverLeave(index)"
                  >
// MOUSE OVER IS NOT UPDATING
                    <div><img :src="mouseOver[index] ? image[1].src : image[0].src"></div>
         </div>
         data() {
            return {
              id: this.$route.params.id,
              images: [],
              mouseOver: []
            };
         },
         mounted() {
          this.returnImages
            this.mouseOver = this.currentCollection.products.map((res) => {
            return false
          })
        },
         methods: {
                hoverEnter(index) {
                  this.mouseOver[index] = true
                },
                hoverLeave(index) {
                  this.mouseOver[index] = false
                },
          },
          watch: {
                mouseOver: function (newValue) {
                  console.log(newValue) // THIS IS NOT UPDATING
                }
          },
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make this reactive using the this.$set from Vue and remove the watch. Edit: Got it, it's splice in nice form. I made my data non reactive. Hope this helps someone.

> When you modify an Array by directly setting an index (e.g. arr[0] = val) or modifying its length property. Similarly, Vue.js cannot pickup these changes. Always modify arrays by using an Array instance method, or replacing it entirely.

they say.https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/

> arr.splice(index, 1, value)

Vue Set

```
   methods: {
    hoverEnter(index) {
      this.$set(this.mouseOver, index, true)
      console.log(this.mouseOver)
    },
    hoverLeave(index) {
      this.$set(this.mouseOver, index, false)
      console.log(this.mouseOver)
    },
  },
```

Splice

```
methods: {
    hoverEnter(index) {
      this.mouseOver.splice(index, 1, true)
      console.log(this.mouseOver)
    },
    hoverLeave(index) {
      this.mouseOver.splice(index, 1, false)
      console.log(this.mouseOver)
    },
  },
```